# is there anything i can do to make this while loop stop?

Tags: python

**I am trying to check if a certain list item is present in a given string?!**

```
str = '[{()'
listt = ['()','{}', '[]']
replace = True

while replace:
  for i in listt:
    if i in str:
      print('y')
      replace == False
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try doing this:

```
str = '[{()'
listt = ['()','{}', '[]']
replace = True

while replace:
  for i in listt:
    if i in str:
      print('y')
      replace = False
```